# Using pandoc in python code via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pandoc

I am writing some Python code that includes `pandoc` via the `subprocess` module. However I'm facing some problems when I try to convert `.md` files to `.pdf` and `.html`, described below:

Firstly,

```
 subprocess.run(["pandoc", "test_1/test1_new.md", "-o", "test_1/testoutput.pdf"])
```

The above brings up the warning :

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'test_t1.png': replacing image with description
```

Having the `.png` file in the same dir as `.md`, why do I get the `.pdf` without the image? using `pandoc` in the command line also throws up the same error.

Secondly,

```
 subprocess.run(["pandoc", "test_1/test1_new.md", "-o", "test_1/testoutput.html"])
```

Now, when I convert `.md` to `.html` file, I do get the `.png` in the output with no warnings, but endup with a `.html` file with no table borders rather just text description.

Is there a way to avoid these errors while converting `.md` files to various formats?

Comment: Image paths are interpreted relative to the current working directory. Checkout the [rebase_relative_paths](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#extension-rebase_relative_paths) Markdown extension and add `"--from=markdown+rebase_relative_paths"`.

Comment: @tarleb providing absolute path also solved the image path issue.